# Product of unsigned measurable function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Terry Tao's book *An Introduction to Measure Theory*, the treatment of measurable functions starts with unsigned functions. He defined measurability of an unsigned function $f$ to be *the existence of a sequence of unsigned simple functions converging to $f$ pointwise.*

Then, other usual properties of measurable functions pops up following this definition. But one of them I found that cannot be derived elegantly as in the co-au book by his former supervisor Elias Stein and Rami Shakarchi's on the subject: it was *measurability of the product of measurable functions*.

In Stein & Shakarchi, measurability is defined for functions with image over the entire real line. Upon knowing addition and integer power preserves measurability, we can use the relation
$$fg=\frac{1}{2}[(f+g)^2-f^2-g^2]$$
to show the measurability of $fg$. However, the argument doesn't work for unsigned functions.

The problem can still be solved by tackling case by case regarding the evaluation of $f(x)g(x)$. My question is: Is there a  way to derive measurability of product simply, without having to tackle case by case as in Stein & Shakarchi's text?